# What are the pitfalls for the simulation of MOF materials with VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I want to study the properties of metal-organic framework (MOF) materials with DFT implemented in VASP. What's the pitfall for this kind of simulation? Which points should I take special care of?

**I will clarify my question with more details as Andrew Rosen suggested.**

- If I want to relax the geometry of the MOF materials, which algorithm do I take (ISIF=?) in VASP?
- If I want to perform a self-consistent calculation with VASP, what do I need to take care of?
- If I want to study the absorption of MOF on atoms, what do I need to take care of?

PS: The original question is split into three questions. They are closely related to the DFT simulation of MOF materials. For convenience, I will link them below:

- [How to obtain MOF structures to perform DFT simulation with VASP?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/how-to-obtain-mof-structures-to-perform-dft-simulation-with-vasp)
- [What're the difference between MOF materials, isolated cluster, and periodical solid?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/whatre-the-difference-between-mof-materials-isolated-cluster-and-periodical-s)

Comment: My expertise is in this area, but your question is currently too vague for useful answers to be written. What are you hoping to model (i.e. what properties or processes)? That might help us give you more direct answers.

Comment: @AndrewRosen Thanks for your suggestions. I have detailed my questions.

Comment: These are all great questions! I am in the midst of writing up answers, but I think you may be better suited by splitting this up a bit into two (or more) posts. In particular, your first question about finding MOF structures isn't related to pitfalls and could stand on its own as a good question. My answer for that is already quite long on its own. @Nike Dattani - thoughts?

Comment: @Dattani How can I split my question?

Comment: You can simply post a new question and edit this one accordingly. At the very least, I'd recommend making a new question asking about where to find MOF structures/databases and then editing this one just to remove that question. Feel free to do the same with any other questions you wish to have more comprehensive answers to. Personally, I would make the first and second questions as two distinct questions and then lump the last three together under one post as a third question.

Comment: @AndrewRosen I have followed your suggestions and reformulated my questions. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewRosen is correct: every question has to be a separate post. You have several sentences ending in question marks. What if someone knows the answer to 2 of the questions but not the third? They might not answer at all because they don't know the answer to the "whole question". If several people answer different sub-questions, then how do we vote the best answer to the top? The best answer for question A might be different from the best answer for question B. Also the comments get messy when there's several questions. Please ask separate questions (this will also get you more points).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend reading ["Electronic Structure Modeling of Metal–Organic Frameworks"](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.chemrev.0c00148) by Mancuso and coworkers for an overview of some subtle considerations when carrying out electronic structure calculations of MOFs.

> If I want to relax the geometry of the MOF materials, which algorithm
> do I take (ISIF=?) in VASP?

There is no single best answer for this. In [prior work](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jcc.25787), I had tested a variety of optimization algorithms for a diverse set of MOF structures. Empirically, I found that using the conjugate gradient (CG) algorithm (`ibrion=2`) is generally both robust and fairly efficient in most cases. When the forces get small (i.e. you get close to the local minimum in the potential energy surface), the CG algorithm can often fail though with MOFs. In these cases, I have empirically found that switching to FIRE (`iopt=7`, `ibrion=3` with [VTST](http://theory.cm.utexas.edu/vtsttools/optimizers.html#fire-parameters-iopt-7)) is generally the best choice. I have used CG $\rightarrow$ FIRE to optimize [tens of thousands of MOF structures](https://chemrxiv.org/articles/preprint/Machine_Learning_the_Quantum-Chemical_Properties_of_Metal_Organic_Frameworks_for_Accelerated_Materials_Discovery_with_a_New_Electronic_Structure_Database/13147616) with great success. The only exception is if the forces are *extremely* high in the initial geometry optimization steps. In these cases, I have empirically found that using [ASE's BFGSLineSearch algorithm](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/optimize.html) for a few steps does a nice job at smoothly resolving the high forces without causing the structure to "explode" or anything like that.

As a side-note, you mentioned the `isif` flag in your question. That does not choose the type of geometry optimization algorithm but rather which degrees of freedom to relax. In general, you should ensure that your material is the minimum energy structure with respect to the atomic positions and cell shape/volume. In other words, use `isif=3`. Typically, when modeling adsorbates with MOFs, the guest-free MOF structure will be optimized with `isif=3` and then the lattice constants fixed thereafter (i.e. `isif=2` is used). This inherently assumes that the lattice constants of the MOF do not change when adsorbates are introduced, which is typically (although not always) true.

> If I want to perform a self-consistent calculation with VASP, what do
> I need to take care of?

In general, nothing special has to be done for MOFs. If you're using VASP as you mention, ensure that your property of interest is converged with respect to the plane-wave kinetic energy cutoff and $k$-point grid.  Make sure you enable spin-polarization if there is any possibility of unpaired electrons in your system. Beyond this, you may find my [prior answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/170/what-are-good-ways-to-reduce-computing-time-when-working-with-large-systems-in-v/172#172) to the question "What are good ways to reduce computing time when working with large systems in VASP?" to be helpful.

> If I want to study the absorption of MOF on atoms, what do I need to
> take care of?

You will need to ensure that you consider various adsorption modes for a given adsorbate. If you don't do this, you may end up modeling a configuration that is not the minimum energy configuration. If the adsorbate induces a change in oxidation state of the MOF, keep in mind that your typical GGA functionals like PBE will probably be fairly insufficient. You can check out [this article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/5.0010166) for some suggestions about modeling the adsorption of species that oxidize metal centers of MOFs. Also, in DFT, people often only include one adsorbate per unit cell, but in reality you should remember that it is very possible multiple adsorbates would be present and there could be adsorbate–adsorbate interactions or coverage-dependent effects.

To systematically add adsorbates to MOFs, you may be interested in the [MOF Adsorbate Initializer](https://github.com/arosen93/mof-adsorbate-initializer) for small molecule adsorbates or the [MOF Big Adsorbate Initializer](https://github.com/haoyuanchen/mof-big-adsorbate-initializer) for larger ones.